# Analogue of Third Sylow Theorem for sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $n=p^em$ such that $p^e$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $n$, and $p\nmid m$. Let $N$ be the number of subsets of order $p^e$ in a set $S$ with $|S|=n$. I want to compute $N\mod p$. Does anyone have an idea?

**Edit:** Can I write $N={n\choose p^e}$ and then find the residue modulo $p$?

Comment: Captain Lama has already provided a solution below, but here are some theorems that will help you solve this sort of problem more generally: [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem), [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer's_theorem), [Wolestenholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme's_theorem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $N$ is clearly $\binom{p^em}{p^e}$, which is $$\prod_{i=0}^{p^e -1}\frac{p^e m-i}{p^e -i}$$
but if $i = p^kq$ with $p\not | q$, then $\frac{p^e m-i}{p^e -i} = \frac{p^{e-k} m-q}{p^{e-k} -q}\equiv 1$ mod $p$, and if $i=0$ then $\frac{p^e m-i}{p^e -i} = m$.

So $N\equiv m$ mod $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Without the group elements, this is just a combinatorial problem, since what makes the group problem interesting is the requirements of subgroups to possess closure, identity, inverses.

Just count the number of ways to add $p^e $ elements, then remove symmetric representations.

EDIT:

Yes to your update